# How to validate selectize element while submitting a form without specific library?

Tags: jquery, validation, selectize.js

I want to validate a selectize element while submitting a form.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/user/edit/2">
    ...
    <div class="selectize">
        <select name="roles" multiple required>
        </select>
    </div>
    ...
    <button type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
var user_roles = $('.selectize select[name="roles[]"]');
var $user_roles = user_roles.selectize({
    options: [{
        value: 'admin',
        label: 'Admin'
    },
    {
        value: 'user',
        label: 'User'
    },
    {
        value: 'developer',
        label: 'Developer'
    }],
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    maxItems: null,
    placeholder: 'Select a role ...',
    valueField: 'value',
    labelField: 'label'
});
...
```

As you can see, I added an attribute to the selectize element `required`.

In that case, if I click submit, it doesn't show anything.

I want to show normal jQuery validation message without any library or add any validate script like the following image if the value of selectize element is empty.

[image: user_roles]

Other fields inside the same form show validation messages like the image except the selectize roles element.

Comment: Its working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shmkv48j/).

Comment: @Swati, Great! But can you tell me what is wrong in my code? Your code looks like the same as mine. It is just selectize version problem? I am using selectize v0.11.0

Comment: Yes , its version issue i tried with 0.11.0 not working .

Comment: @Swati, Got it. Can you answer to this question so I can check it as the answer.

Comment: HI, you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

It was because of selectize version issue.

Downgrading the version 0.11.0 to 0.8.5 worked for me. So I think we should report the bug or new feature even downgrading works.